# Get value from store procedure and write to textbox

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, textbox

I'm using vb.net and I'm running SP, Returning value 4 rows and 3 cols. I'm showing in datagridview but i want to show specific cell ex. row 1 col 3 in textbox > How can i do that?

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  This is not a tutorial site.  Do some research. try some stuff, then ask here as a last resort when you are stuck

Comment: Its my first question as you can  see i don't know rules thank you for your recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using datatable to fill the data , and later you want to move the data to text box you can use.

```
Dim lcon As SqlConnection
    Dim lsqlcom As New SqlCommand
    Dim lsqldataAdpter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ldattable As New DataTable

        lcon = GetSQLConnection()
        lsqlcom.Connection = lcon
        lsqlcom.CommandText = "testdata"
        lsqlcom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        lsqldataAdpter = New SqlDataAdapter(lsqlcom)
        lsqldataAdpter.Fill(ldattable)
        TextBox1.Text = ldattable.Rows(1).Item(3)'fill the data in text box
```

if you want to get the data from Datagridview you can use

```
TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(3).Value
```